# How to get around server flooding by users opening countless tabs?

Tags: php, ajax

I have some kind of chat/forum application that checks for new messages using periodic polling (every 15 seconds) using jquery ajax. I was wondering if i can get around the issue of users who try to be 'funny' by loading several same browser instances, with lots of tabs, all pointing to the same application. Each tab is sending an ajax request, which potentially can overflow a server if several users start to do the same thing.

I do store sessions in a table, along with the last access time and IP address, which works fine as long as users don't use the same browser. I could store a unique identifyer that is sent using the ajax POST or GET request, but that would give problems if a regular (non abusing) user refreshes his page, which would then create a new identifyer.

This is not a real problem yet, but better catch it before someone thinks of abusing the system like this :) Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that you could potentially do is some sort of rate limiting (i.e.: limit the number of polling requests per session / time period).

Comment: Hmm, that is something i didn't think of yet. I do have limiting of some sort which stops ajax polling after 5 minutes of inactivity, but i could expand it a bit.

Comment: Actually, that can't really be done using PHP, since that still requires an ajax request. Is it possible to limit it using javascript? In other words, do all tabs in the same browser know of eachother and eachother's requests, and limit it that way by using javacsript? Basically, is there an internal browser counter that sees that a request has just been done in tab X, and have code in there so that tab Y wont be sending ajax requests anymore?

Comment: JS variables are reinstantiated with every page load, so no the variables cannot be shared across tabs. However, you could send a request on page load to a server-side script that keeps track of the # of requests and sends it back down to the client before anything else executes.

Comment: Could you store a timestamp in that user's session of when the messages were last retrieved? Then regardless of what browser/tab they are using, PHP can check against that and ensure the allotted time has elapsed.

Comment: @Brian, That still uses an apache process. Most of the polling requests return empty (no update) which is very fast, but if you scale it up with a lot of users, and this hypothetical user that tries to abuse/flood the server, apache may still lock up with too many requests... even if nothing is really being processed on the server side. What i am looking for is something where the ajax is completely shut off on all other browser tabs for this specific app.

Comment: @Sempiterna I don't think that's really possible from the client side. Browser tabs are unaware of other browser tabs generally.

Comment: @NightHawk, i do store timestamps, but the checking still uses 1 apache process every 15 sec.

Comment: @Brian, yea it probably won't be possible that way then. One other user posted an 'answer' (which he unfortunately deleted) to use APE, which would kind of solve the problem of new processes for every request. But that that is something that, eventhough i have looked at that for quite a while, i haven't got a clue how to work with :(

Comment: This is a work for websockets. Unfortunately I haven't used them yet so I owe you a link

Comment: @TheDisintegrator , yea that would be the perfect solution, and i have looked at that (APE, NodeJS, etc) but i haven't got a clue how to work with those.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to fetch data like so:

- Your script is preparing to poll data. Before executing the request, write (with [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)), a value saying that you're going to fetch data. `localStorage.setItem("last-request-timestamp", new Date().getTime());`
- Poll for data. You get a result. Write that result to the localStorage: `localStorage.setItem("latest-messages", ajax_result);`
- Check if a page is preparing to poll data by checking if `localStorage.getItem("last-request-timestamp")` is longer than 15 seconds ago. If so, go to step 1. If not, wait 15 seconds and check again.
- Regardless if the current page polled for data or not, check the `latest-messages` variable and update the page.

Other pages will of course share the localStorage data. They won't get data if another page is fetching at the moment. If page #1 is closed, one of the other pages will continue to fetch data.

I haven't used LocalStorage before, but browser support seems decent enough. You should also be able to just use it as a key-value array: `localStorage["last-request-timestamp"]`.

You can only store strings in localStorage, but you can of course serialize it into JSON.

Comment: Interesting, i hadn't heard about this before. I assume this can be set and used inside the jquery code blocks, so that this only applies to certain requests. I will look into this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem. Now I force all users to log in (it means i have their e-mails). Also i setup connections limit per account and request limit per connection, after 5 overflows i ask user to enter captcha, then i block account for a 30 min and send e-mail with password recovery link. It's not a clear solution but for now it works for me.

**UPD:**

The simplest way to do this is to use cookie or session storage. I use cookies. The algorithm is simple:

1. User login on web.
2. Check is there any opened session for this user,
   is opened, then delete the other session or trigger exception or
   switch to that session, you have decide your own the desired
   behavior.
3. Create session id for user and store it in database.
4. Increase sessions counter field for specific user to detect opened
   sessions, so now it doesn't matter is there one browser in use
   or many.
5. Update last access mark (i use `microtime(true) + $delay` and mysql
   `decimal(14,4)`). Send it to user
6. Send id to client

On each request:

1. Search for session by passed id in $_COOKIE.
2. Check last access mark. If it less then `microtime(true)` it means that client send requests to frequent, so decide yourself what to do, increase the mark, for example `microtime(true) + $delay + $penalty` or drop whole session or trigger error. The behavior depends of your application.

Comment: How do you get the number of connections for a user if this user connects multiple times from the same browser? A unique identifyer that is sent with every POST or GET? A request limit would be useless, since that would still require an ajax request to be sent to the server, where it is being checked if the limit is reached.

Comment: @RikkusRukkus it is not safe to rely on localStorage, because its data could be modified by user

Comment: Sessions and cookies are all for the same session/domain, so i am not sure if this would work in my case. I will see if i can test this. About the LocalStorage. I think only a fraction of regular users would know how to manipulate the LocalStorage data, so that would probably rule out most of those 'pranksters'. I woul dprobably only store the 'last execution time' in such LocalStorage var.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is do-able in javascript. You can check if the tab is active. And only do the ajax on the active tab?

Comment: That may be an idea to look at using onfocus/onblur or something. Not sure if that works in all browsers and mobile, but it is worth a test.

Answer (score 0):

Why not throw something like Memcached/Redis at the problem?  Cache a response with a 10-15s lifetime and avoid as much processing as possible.